# Scan resources in concrete package with org.reflections

Tags: java, reflection

I'm using [org.reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) to find resources in package:

```
new Reflections(
    "test", //package prefix
    new ResourcesScanner()
).getResources(x -> x.endsWith(".xml"))
```

It worked fine until package with similar name was added. 
E.g. it was only package `test` and added package `test_second`:

```
| 
+-+-[test]
| +--one.xml
| +--two.xml
|
+-+-[test_second]
  +--three.xml
  +--four.xml
```

Now resources from both packages are found when I trying to scan it by prefix.

**Question:** how to scan resources only in "test" package using this library and ignore all other packages with "test" prefix?

Answer (score 1):

I Know, its a bit late, but you have to add a `.` at the end of your package prefix: `"test."`. We use it a bit different, but solved the exact same problem you had:

```java
String location = "test.";
Collection<URL> urls = ClasspathHelper.forPackage(location);
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .setScanners(new ResourcesScanner())
                    .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().includePackage(location))
                    .setUrls(urls));
Set<String> resources = reflections.getResources(x -> x.endsWith(".xml"));
```

NOTE: This example is working with `0.9.x`. Currently I'm working on migrationg this to `0.10.x`.